# Do the Java and JavaFX versions have to match?

Tags: java, javafx

Do the version of Java and JavaFX have to match?

For example, can I combine Java 11 with JavaFX 13, or Java12 with JavaFX 10?

I tried and it seems to work, but I wonder if it is fully supported.

Comment: Even if you can, why would you want to do that? Just use the latest JavaFX together with the latest Java and you will be safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a requirement for them to match to full work toghether. Still you have to be aware of the minimum requirements for your JavaFX to work with a given JDK.

Besides, JavaFX will continue to live as an independent project as [OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io/)

**Note : JavaFX is no more included in JDK since JDK 11**

Comment: Thank you! I noticed Java 11+ is recommended for JavaFX.

Comment: Since JDK 11 not 12